# random_state maintained when running script again?

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn

Suppose I have a program, called `script.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,5,6,3], "y": [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]})

    train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 100)
```

If I run this script from my command line once:

```
H:\>python script.py
```

How can I ensure that the `train` and `test` dataframes in subsequent runs (i.e. when I run `script.py` again) are identical to the `train` and `test` dataframes from previous iterations? I know the `random_state` works if you don't leave the console, but would the equality of these `train` and `test` sets be preserved if I came back tomorrow, turned my PC back on, and re-ran `script.py`?

I am testing the accuracies of different machine learning algorithms, all stored in different scripts, which is why I want to make sure the train and test sets are identical across scripts.

Comment: For a DataFrame of same shape, it will return the same splits, yes. You can try it with your example. I have indices 7 and 6 in the test dataset. You should have the same.

Answer (score 1):

Random state how nothing to do with when you run your code. The whole concept of specifing random state is to have **exactly the same results every time you run this code with the same parameters**. So as long as you do not change df, test_size and random_state, this function will always return the same values, no matter how many days pass. It might, however, change if you update the underlying library.

Comment: So, holding everything constant, except for the time at which I run my script, I will get the same splits above when using the same value for `random_state`? How does Python know in a completely different script using the same dataframe, that if I specify `random_state = 100`, it should split the df identically as in the other script?

Comment: It is because internally, df splitting uses a random number generator which, given a random_state is **a deterministic function**. So there is no randomness when you set the seed, it is just a regular function, involving some bit manipulation, but in a fully deterministic manner. This is also the reason why we do not really have random numbers in CS, we only have **pseudo**random numbers.